# How can i use the database column type geography in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, linq-to-nhibernate, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.9

In Orchard CMS does anyone know how i can create a geography database column type I need this in order to do a deferred query on distance

Comment: I had the same question a year ago and ended up implementing everything with simpler types. I think it is still not supported.